# Method won't allow string to be returned

Tags: java, recursion, random, passwords

I have a method to generate a random password recursively, which is required to have at least one uppercase letter. I have the method set up, but for some reason it's telling me that the method must have a return of type String when I've already defined a `return` type in my if statement.

**Question: How can I make this error go away or fix my method in order to have it return a password?**

```
public static char[]chars = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m',
                'n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5',
                '6','7','8','9','!','@','$','%','^','&'};

            public static String generatePassword(Random rand, String password, int position, int size) //this method must return a result of type String
            {
                boolean isLowerCase = rand.nextBoolean();
                int randomChar = rand.nextInt(chars.length);
                char c = chars[randomChar];
                if(position == size) //base case
                {
                    return password; //string is returned here? 
                }
                if(isLowerCase)
                {
                    generatePassword(rand, password + c, position + 1, size);
                }
                else //its either upper or lower case
                {
                    generatePassword(rand, password + Character.toUpperCase(c), position + 1, size);
                }
```

Comment: `return generatePassword(rand, password + c, position + 1, size);` (and the other `else` condition)...?

Answer (score 2):

In your method for all the combinations of execution there should be a String returning. Here's how your method should look like.

```
    public static String generatePassword(Random rand, String password, int position, int size) //this method must return a result of type String
    {
        boolean isLowerCase = rand.nextBoolean();
        int randomChar = rand.nextInt(chars.length);
        char c = chars[randomChar];
        if(position == size) //base case
        {
            return password; //string is returned here? 
        }
        if(isLowerCase)
        {
            return generatePassword(rand, password + c, position + 1, size);
        }
        else //its either upper or lower case
        {
            return generatePassword(rand, password + Character.toUpperCase(c), position + 1, size);
        }
     }
```

Comment: I see, I had just assumed that having a return type would satisfy the conditions. Didn't realize you always had to be returning something each time, but I suppose that makes sense when you think about it. Thank you very much, @Eranda! This seemed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a poor place for a recursive solution to me, I suggest you use a `StringBuilder` and a single `static Random`. Along with a single `size` parameter to your method. Something like,

```
private static Random rand = new Random();
public static String generatePassword(int size) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int randomChar = rand.nextInt(chars.length);
        char ch = chars[randomChar];
        if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            if (rand.nextBoolean()) {
                ch = Character.toUpperCase(ch);
            }
        }
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```